# BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str) error

Tags: python, azure, blob

I am trying to upload JSON file into a new container on Azure blob Storage account.
[I use Microsoft quick guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python)
Currently my code looks like this:

```
>import os, uuid
>from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
>connect_str = os.getenv('AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING')

So far It's works OK but when I add this line
>blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
```

I get an error message:

```
>(base) "`my file path`"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "`my file path`", line 14, in <module>
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
  File `".../anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_blob_service_client.py"`, line 174, in from_connection_string
    account_url, secondary, credential = parse_connection_str(conn_str, credential, 'blob')
  File `".../anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/base_client.py"`, line 363, in parse_connection_str
    conn_str = conn_str.rstrip(";")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

I had wrote the same code on my PC and about a month ago I moved to Mac OS. I thought I did all the relevant adjustments, but apparently not.
Since this mac is completely new I think I missing a few packages or maybe hav the wrong versions of the packages.

**I am attaching pip list:**

azure-common                       1.1.27

azure-core                         1.12.0

azure-nspkg                        3.0.2

azure-storage                      0.36.0

azure-storage-blob                 12.9.0

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your environment variable is probably not found.
Try this code

```
connect_str = os.environ['AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING']
```

It should raise a `KeyError` or return `None`.
I think you should be sure the variable is really read or that its value is not `None`.

Comment: I think it's returned none:

    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING'